# How can I break into Python code called from Python.NET on a separate thread?

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, pycharm, python.net

I would like to use PyCharm's debugger to stop at a breakpoint set in a **Python method which is called from C# via Python.NET**. However, the breakpoint is never hit, even though the code clearly gets executed.

The issue seems to be that the thread on which the Python method is called was created in C#. I am aware that for a thread to be visible to the debugger, `settrace` must be called. I thought, calling it once per thread should do the trick, but it does not. Because after calling `settrace` at the first execution of a Python method, my breakpoints in that method and any methods called by it, are hit. But after control passed from that method back to C#, another call of a Python method on the same thread does not hit the breakpoint.

Here is the Python side of things; imagine breakpoints set at the two `print` statements.

```
import sys
import thread
import threading

sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev')
import pydevd


import clr
from System.Threading import Thread
from System import Action


sys.path.append(r'C:\Code\PythonNetLib\bin\Debug')
clr.AddReference('MyLib')
from MyLib import MyThread, MyThreadBase


def init_debugging():
    pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
    # breakpoint here is hit
    print 'debugging initialized in thread {0}, managed thread ID {1}'.format(thread.get_ident(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)  


def hello():
    # pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
    # breakpoint here is not hit unless pydevd.settrace is called again
    print 'Hello from thread {0}, managed thread ID {1}'.format(thread.get_ident(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))  

t = MyThread()
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(init_debugging))
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(hello))
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(t.Stop))
t.Join()
```

For illustration purposes here is a simplified version of the C# library referenced above containing the `MyThread` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyLib
{
   public class MyThread: MyThreadBase
   {
       private Thread _thread;

       public MyThread()
       {
         _thread = new Thread(Execute);
         _thread.Start();
       }

       public void Join()
       {
          _thread.Join();
      }
    }

   public class MyThreadBase
   {
      private ConcurrentQueue<Action> _queue;
      private bool _stopped;

      public MyThreadBase()
      {
         _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
      }

      public void Execute()
      {
         while (!_stopped)
         {
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out Action action))
            {
               action();
            }
            else
            {
               Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
         }
      }

      public void ExecuteAsync(Action action)
      {
         _queue.Enqueue(action);
      }

      public void Stop()
      {
         _stopped = true;
      }
   }
}
```

**Workaround:** I noticed that my breakpoints are hit as expected when I don't create the thread in C# but use a Python thread instead like so:

```
t = MyThreadBase()
tPy = threading.Thread(target=lambda: t.Execute())
tPy.start()
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(init_debugging))
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(hello))
t.ExecuteAsync(Action(t.Stop))
tPy.join()
```

This is an option in some cases, but I do not control all thread creations in the C# libraries I want to use.

**Question:** What would I have to do make C# threads known to the Python debugger permanently such that the debugger doesn't lose sight of the thread after control passes back to C#. Repeatedly calling `settrace` seems a bit much, particularly since I can't know definitively which methods might all get called from C#.

I am using Python 2.7 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: have you looked at this? i have not been able to get pycharm debugger working. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Various-debugging-scenarios-of-embedded-CPython

Comment: @denfromufa yes, looked at it, but none of the information there seemed applicable to debugging with PyCharm, which for better or worse is the IDE I have to work with.